# Macbook Pro Mighty Mouse Tracking Speed Slow

Tags: mouse, macbook-pro, mighty-mouse

I am using Mighty Mouse on my Macbook Pro. Tracking speed is extremely slow. While in the System preference > Mouse > Tracking speed is full. How can i increase speed according to my needs?

Comment: Have you tried using a mouse mat? The Might Mouse is really fussy with work surfaces.

Comment: Yeah! I am using mouse mat. Actually i am windows user just switch from window to mac. In windows mouse is very smooth and fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give your mouse speed an extra boost, try BetterTouchTool. http://www.boastr.de/

I also use this to block fullscreen mode.

Comment: I just install BTT! But having message in the mouse settings > Set mouse speed (unfortunately starting with macOS Sierra, the speed can't be higher than the maximum in the System Preference)

Comment: There's a lot of people with this problem in sierra - There's another mouse tool available here http://www.plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/

Comment: Great! its work :)